# HTTP 403.9 - Access Forbidden: error

Tags: iis-5

I`ve been constantly getting the same error,like
  "HTTP 403.9 - Access Forbidden: Too many users are connected Internet Information Services Technical Information".
I went through this site and found this command ->
"C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil set w3svc/MaxConnections 40" to set maximum connections.Even after running this command I still have the same error.
I`m using IIS V.5.1,Oracle 10g,IE 9.0.
Is there a better way to fix???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bigger number.

If you've got enough money to pay for licencing MS IIS and Oracle then you should be able to afford hardware to support more than 40 concurrent requests (not got your setup / code here to test - I'd expect that the cheapest PC I could buy today would support over 500 concurrent connections running Linux,Apache and MySQL/Postgress).

Comment: "HTTP KEEP-Alives enabled" in iis I disabled...and it worked fine